# about using boost::geometry::model::polygon with std::list as a container

Tags: boost, polygon, boost-geometry, stdlist

I tried the sample code from Boost [webpage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/area/area_1.html) it works fine - calculates the area of polygon. The documentation for polygon class tells us that it is possible to use different container for vertices: vector (the default), list and deque.

So, I decided to use the std::list container. But compiler (Visual Studio 2017 and gcc as well) returned a lot of errors related to iterators not defined for std::list for the following lines:

```
BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE(RandomAccessIteratorConcept)
{
    i += n;
    i = i + n;
    i = n + i;
    i -= n;
    i = i - n;
    n = i - j;
}
```

and

```
BOOST_concept(Convertible,(X)(Y))
{
    BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE(Convertible) {
        Y y = x;
        ignore_unused_variable_warning(y);
    }
    private:
    X x;
};
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. You don't say where and how exactly, according to you, the documentation states that *"it is possible to use different container for vertices: vector (the default), list and deque*".

According to the documentation of the [Polygon Concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_polygon.html) the ring types must fulfil the Ring Concept.

According to the documentation of that [Ring Concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_ring.html) `std::list<>` is out of the question, because:

> - it must behave like a Boost.Range Random Access Range

`std::list`'s iterators are not [random access iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) so clearly that contradicts your claim. (Note that the requirements listed on cppreference closely mirror those that you list in your question).

Comment: Hmm, in the link I mentioned in the topic I read "The area algorithm calculates the surface area of all geometries having a surface, namely box, polygon, ring, multipolygon..." and the sample uses the polygon object with std::vector container for vertices.  The documentation for boost geometry polygon (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_polygon.html) describes the template argument list and for PointList it says "container type for points, for example std::vector, std::list, std::deque".

Comment: I know that std::list doesn't support random access iterators, just wanted to confirm, that what I do according to documentation is correct.  So, it seems to me either area() implementation is not  correct or documentation is not accurate.  Am I right?